# How to set retry config for Google Cloud Function (Firebase function scheduled using Google Pub/Sub) - Node.js 8

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a cron job task which is defined as a Firebase function and executed using Google Pub/Sub Scheduler.

```js
exports.executeTask = functions.pubsub.schedule('every wednesday 00:00').timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
  .onRun((context) => {
      // Cron job logic...
  })
```

I wish to set retry configuration for this scheduler function to retry max three times on failure. I'm writing code using **Node.js 8** and there is `.retryConfig()` function for the above line which accepts an object of **`ScheduleRetryConfig`** as a parameter to set schedule retry configuration. How can I initialise the **ScheduleRetryConfig** object with the right retry options and pass it in `.retryConfig()`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the API we find that:

`functions.pubsub.schedule()` returns a ScheduleBuilder object that has a function on it called `retryConfig`.  This function is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_pubsub_.schedulebuilder.html#retryconfig).   We see that the function takes an object as a parameter.  The object's nature is as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_configuration_.scheduleretryconfig.html).  We are told the properties of the object and see that they are all optional.  One property is called `retryCount`.

What this means is that you can code:

```
exports.executeTask = functions.pubsub.schedule('every wednesday 00:00')
  .retryConfig({
    retryCount: 3
  })
  .timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
  .onRun((context) => {
      // Cron job logic...
  })
```

Comment: Do you know what format the properties like minBackoffDuration accept? It's not specified in the [ScheduleRetryConfig specification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_configuration_.scheduleretryconfig).

Comment: Searching, it appears to be a number terminated by "s" for seconds.  This makes me think that we can specify other codes ... maybe "h" for hour or "d" for day.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. For some reason though, adding retryConfig updates the Scheduler task on each deploy.